# I don't understand this error "Attribute iframe not allowed on element iframe at this point." w3c

Tags: html

I don't understand this error :

"Attribute iframe not allowed on element iframe at this point.
From line 192, column 17; to line 192, column 373"

If you need more code tell me.

```
<div id="map"><iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2624.2216096807224!2d2.347636915674888!3d48.87305177928887!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47e66e145ccb3091%3A0x9495beee8c96ec27!2s25+Rue+d&#39;Hauteville%2C+75010+Paris!5e0!3m2!1sfr!2sfr!4v1546423495666" width="600" height="750" iframe style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Its seems that you have added Iframe as attribute after height="750"; remove it and check. this may resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have an element (tag) of `<iframe>` containing multiple attributes, one of which is the word `iframe` (`... height="750" iframe style="border:0" ...`).

The validator is saying that the attribute `iframe` is not recognised - there is no such attribute [defined in the standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/iframe-embed-object.html#the-iframe-element), so it shouldn't be there.

Comment: I have removed iframe and it's ok. Thanks a lot.